# using or statement to define variable in javascript

Tags: javascript

can someone explain me why my code isn't working as I want to?

```
test = function(argument){
var arg = argument || true;
console.log(arg)
};
test(false);
```

and return is always true. I thought that it will only be true if argument is `'undefined'`?
thanks for answers! :)

Comment: It might make more sense if you compare it with equality checking. Say `x = 2`, then `if(x === 1 || x === 2) { ... }` is executed (as you would expect) because it simplifies to `false || true`, which is `true`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`||` is the logical or operator. So `false OR true` evaluates to `true`.

`undefined` is `falsey` as well, so its a short hand for returning the right-hand side of the operator.

You might want this instead

```
var arg = typeof argument !== 'undefined' ? argument : true;
```

Answer (score 5):

It will print `true` if the `argument` is *falsy*, i.e.:

- `false`
- `null`
- `undefined`
- empty string
- number `0`
- number `NaN`

e.g.:

```
'' || true
```

will evaluate to `true`.

Answer (score 2):

change it to:

```
var arg=(typeof argument!=='undefined'?argument:true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Logically anything `ORed` with `true` is always a `true`.

lets see the truth table for A and B

```
A   B  A || B 
T   T    T     <-- one of them is true
T   F    T     <-- one of them is true
F   T    T     <-- one of them is true
F   F    F     <-- only both false can create a false in an OR operation.
```

Comment: `true` and `1` are both truthy, so you get that, whatever you OR it with on the right hand side.

Comment: So the statement "Anything ORed with true is always a true" is not correct. `something || otherthing` will either return the value of `something` if it's truethy or the value of `otherthing`, even if the value of `otherthing` is falsey.

Answer (score 1):

```
var test = function(argument){
  var arg = typeof argument === "undefined" ? true : argument;
  console.log(arg);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [ECMA-262 11.11](http://es5.github.com/#x11.11), a logical OR statement returns the **value** of the first truethy expression or the value of the last expression if no previous expression is truethy.